# Error when setting up wireless share between two Ubuntu laptops on home network

Tags: networking

I have two laptops: an Acer Aspire 5742 and Aspire V15.  Both are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Both connect to my home wireless router and have access to the internet and wireless printer so network is working.  I want to share files and folders between the two.  I have set up shared folders and when I did so I was prompted to install networking software which I did. (I assume smba.) When I go to the Network option on the file manager there is a network there called 'Windows Network'.  When I click this I get the following message:  "Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory".  The Ubuntu documentation suggests that local sharing should just work (like it does on Windows) so all answers to this, that I have found, simply refer back to the Ubuntu documentation.  What am I doing wrong please.
Thanks
Clinton

Comment: Also I have checked if samba exists on both these laptops using samba --version and this returns "Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu"

Comment: Also I just ran smbstatus and got Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
PID     Username      Group         Machine            Protocol Version       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------

No locked files

Comment: Connect to server as smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (where the Xs represent the IP address of the computer sharing the folders.

Comment: Sorry just hit return by mistake.   I now see the list of shared folders but when I click on them I get a window asking for  Connect as registered user or anonymous - then boxes for username, domain and password.  I dont know what these are or where to look for them.  The username prompts my Ubuntu username and the domain is WORKGROUP.  Ive tried the username and logon password for both laptops.  Sorry to ask for help again. Thanks Clinton

Comment: Just found this on Ubuntu Forums 'sudo smbpasswd -a <username>'.  This has worked on one of the laptops but not the other??